# Which test methodology is best for testing the whole Django REST application?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Which test methodology is best for testing the whole **Django REST** application ?

I have found two methodologies

1. http://heynemann.github.io/pyvows/ (It looks Ok, its for django)
2. Django Unit Test (this is not good for big project, its for django)

Could you please share your best test methodology which you come across !!

Comment: Despite the 'closed as opinion based' I'm going to answer this regardless: Testing using the Django test client is almost always the best place to start - you can get a good amount of sanity-checking coverage for not too much work. These are *almost* functional-level tests, although you're not testing in a real browser. I'd expect any decent Django project to be well covered with client test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully cover a large application on all levels you'll want three kinds of tests. From lowest to highest level you'll want

- Unit Tests: Tests to make sure that each individual class, or even better, method does what you expect at a logic level. Here you call your methods and assert that expected conditions are true. I have not used PyVows but it seems that PyVows would be a useful tool for unit testing. Django Unit Testing framework is also very sufficient for this.
- Integration Tests: Larger tests that ensure the different classes or apps within the entire django project work together as expected.
- Functional Tests: Tests that simulate user actions and ensure that these actions are handled correctly, call the correct methods, and display/process the correct information based on user interaction. A tool like Selenium Webdriver is useful for functional testing.

To learn how to write well-tested django applications I highly recommend reading the book [Test-Driven Development with Python](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754), by Dan O'Reilly. It is a free read online and gives a great introduction to writing highly testable applications, stressing the benefits of TDD.